# Need a R package for piecewise linear regression?

Tags: r, regression

Is anybody aware of a package for piecewise linear regression?

Comment: Just be careful with that sort of analysis. http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2010/04/iterative_hockey_stick_analysi.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might also want to check out the breakpoints function in the strucchange package.
I've used it when I've had an unknown number of breakpoints.
It's easy to use and has good documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the segmented package

Answer (score 5):

there's a function called `piecewise.linear` in the [SiZer package](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/SiZer/man/piecewise.linear.html).

Searching [RSeek.org](http://www.rseek.org/) is often a good place to start for instances like this where you want to know if something exists already.

Answer (score 0):

There is a M5P method in RWeka package. This is a regression tree with linear equations in leaves. Example code

```
library("RWeka")
MT_model <- M5P(DEP ~ ., data = my_data)
```

There are some parameters to be tuned…

```
  MT_model <- M5P(DEP ~ ., data = my_data, control = Weka_control(M = 4, N =  FALSE, U = TRUE, R = FALSE))
```

To see the description of tunning parameters:

```
WOW('M5P')
```

But there is also caret package that can tune your parameters automatically.

```
library(caret)
train(DEP ~ ., data = my_data, method = 'M5')
```