# Interpolate between observations (piecewise approximation) R

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm comparing some forecast data against actual values. The forecasts are obtained from three different providers. However, the time stamps for the actual data and the forecast data are not the same. I want to compare the error for each point where are forecast was made.

In the below snapshot, I'd like to get the difference of the forecast for each providers forecast from the actual value. The encircled points represent forecasts for which the actual data is not available but we can see there is a distinct trend. I think I would be okay with a piecewise approximation but i'm not sure how to do that. I've seen the answers posted in [Need a R package for piecewise linear regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854513/need-a-r-package-for-piecewise-linear-regression) but it's not very helpful.

10-day sample:
[image]

1-day sample showing the offset b/w forecast instances and actual data:
[image]

sample data (for 1 day)

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(tme = structure(c(1516221000, 1516224600, 1516228200, 
1516231800, 1516235400, 1516239000, 1516242600, 1516246200, 1516249800, 
1516253400, 1516257000, 1516260600, 1516264200, 1516267800, 1516271400, 
1516275000, 1516278600, 1516282200, 1516285800, 1516289400, 1516293000, 
1516296600, 1516300200, 1516303800, 1516307400, 1516226400, 1516230000, 
1516233600, 1516237200, 1516240800, 1516244400, 1516248000, 1516251600, 
1516255200, 1516258800, 1516262400, 1516266000, 1516269600, 1516273200, 
1516276800, 1516280400, 1516284000, 1516287600, 1516291200, 1516294800, 
1516298400, 1516302000, 1516305600, 1516221000, 1516224600, 1516228200, 
1516231800, 1516235400, 1516239000, 1516242600, 1516246200, 1516249800, 
1516253400, 1516257000, 1516260600, 1516264200, 1516267800, 1516271400, 
1516275000, 1516278600, 1516282200, 1516285800, 1516289400, 1516293000, 
1516296600, 1516300200, 1516303800, 1516307400, 1516233600, 1516244400, 
1516255200, 1516266000, 1516276800, 1516287600, 1516298400), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), degc = c(2.25, 1.69, 2.22, 2.22, 1.65, 1.12, 2.22, 
1.1, 1.13, 2.82, 5.58, 7.8, 7.85, 8.43, 10.05, 10.06, 10.07, 
10.03, 8.89, 6.17, 5.04, 5.01, 3.92, 2.29, 2.29, -1, -1, -1, 
-1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
-0.16, -1.13, -2.19, -2.98, -3.48, -3.86, -3.84, -2.96, -1.16, 
0.91, 2.61, 3.92, 4.84, 5.59, 6.68, 7.41, 6.82, 5.08, 3.07, 1.56, 
0.51, -0.36, -1.15, -1.86, -2.53, -0.2, -0.9, 4.1, 6.9, 8.1, 
3.6, 2.6), rh = c(0.55, 0.6, 0.51, 0.51, 0.6, 0.52, 0.55, 0.57, 
0.6, 0.49, 0.44, 0.41, 0.38, 0.36, 0.33, 0.33, 0.31, 0.33, 0.35, 
0.39, 0.4, 0.4, 0.43, 0.49, 0.49, 73, 73, 75, 75, 75, 71, 67, 
59, 52, 47, 42, 39, 37, 35, 34, 37, 43, 48, 51, 54, 58, 61, 62, 
0.61, 0.64, 0.67, 0.7, 0.72, 0.74, 0.74, 0.71, 0.65, 0.58, 0.54, 
0.52, 0.51, 0.5, 0.46, 0.44, 0.45, 0.5, 0.57, 0.61, 0.64, 0.65, 
0.67, 0.69, 0.71, 59.1, 62.6, 43.9, 36.7, 33.2, 46.4, 50.1), 
    type = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", 
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", 
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", 
    "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", 
    "Actual", "Actual", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", 
    "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", 
    "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", 
    "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", 
    "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", "Provider W", 
    "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", 
    "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", 
    "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", 
    "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", 
    "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", "Provider D", 
    "Provider B", "Provider B", "Provider B", "Provider B", "Provider B", 
    "Provider B", "Provider B")), .Names = c("tme", "degc", "rh", 
"type"), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000120788>)
```

I'm really not sure on how to proceed with this. I need to repeat this exercise for several datasets (a few hundred rows each) with up to 30 variables (sample data only has two).

Comment: At time instant "t" I have a forecast value from Provider D (let's call it d_t) but the actual values are only known at "t-10 minutes" (a_{t-10}) and "t+30 minutes"(a_{t+30}). I want to interpolate between the actual values to get an estimate at "t" (a_t) and the difference a_t - d_t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that what you are asking for is this.

```
fAct = approxfun(dt$tme[dt$type=='Actual'], dt$degc[dt$type=='Actual'], )
```

This gives a piecewise linear approximation to the Actual values.  You can then compare this with values from the various providers. For example,

```
> dt[35,]
                   tme degc rh       type
35 2018-01-18 07:00:00    6 47 Provider W
> fAct(dt[35,'tme'])
[1] 6.69
```

So Provider W predicts that degc will be 6 at time 2018-01-18 07:00:00. The (approximation to the) Actual value is 6.69 so the error is 0.69.

### Edit

As noted by @RalfStubner,  you can get a smoother (non-linear) approximation using

```
fAct2 = splinefun(dt$tme[dt$type=='Actual'], dt$degc[dt$type=='Actual'])
```

Comment: Thanks! You're right, this is what I wanted. `approxfun` allows linear or constant approximation and other variables in my dataset (not shown here for brevity) are known to have a non-linear relationship (cubic/quartic). Is there something to do multivariate piecewise nonlinear approximation?

Comment: Have a look at `spline` or `splinefunc` for non-linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `approx` like this to create a linear interpolation of the actual values at each time point for provider W:

```
interpolated <- approx(x = dt[dt$type ==  "Actual", ]$tme, 
                       y = dt[dt$type ==  "Actual", ]$degc, 
                       xout = dt[dt$type ==  "Provider W", ]$tme)
dt[dt$type ==  "Provider W", ]$degc - interpolated$y
#  [1] -2.955 -3.220 -2.935 -2.385 -2.670 -1.660 -0.115  0.025 -0.200 -0.690 -0.825 -0.140 -1.240 -1.055 -1.065 -1.050 -2.460
# [18] -1.530 -1.605 -2.025 -2.465 -1.105 -1.290
```